# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in Laravel 9 shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 9 and this is working fine in my localhost. but when i deploy it with shared hosting on hostgrator and click contact form it is encountered following error messages
`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

I have following contact form in the blade file

```
<div class="content">
@include('partials.alerts')
    <h1 class="heading">Contact Us</h1>
    
    
    <form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}#contact">
        {{method_field('POST')}}
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form">
  <div class="input-flex">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('name'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="tel" class="full-width" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone number*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('telephone'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <textarea cols="2" rows="2" class="full-width" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>
  <button  class="conbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('form','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store');

Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@verifyUser');
```

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: `#contact` in your action won't do anything, as it's an anchor link, and the server will ignore it. Open up your browser's developer console and watch the Network tab when you submit the form. Is it redirecting on submit, such as going form HTTP -> HTTPS?

Comment: it is https and #contact is id to redirect id section on scrolling page

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clear route cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

It's help me

Comment: you know how it is in live shared hosting i am very new for live server

Comment: You can contact server support about that!

Comment: You can run artisan commands in using Artisan::call('optimize:clear');

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using Laravel 9 but the syntax you're using is in old format.
Try updating to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('form') }}#contact">
    @csrf
    <div class="form">
        <div class="input-flex">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /><br><br>
            <span style="color:red">@error('name'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" /><br><br>
            <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
            <input type="tel" class="full-width" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone number*" /><br><br>
            <span style="color:red">@error('telephone'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
            <textarea cols="2" rows="2" class="full-width" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="conbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also update the routes:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::post('form', [UserController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', [UserController::class, 'verifyUser']);
```

You may also create a route that runs optimize clear:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Route::get('/optimize-clear', function () {
    Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
    return 'Optimize cache cleared';
});
```

Let us know if this solves the problem.